# Creating sub domain for each user Asp.Net application

Tags: c#, iis

I am trying to create sub domain for users registering on my website. Example username.mydomain.com
user2.mydomain.com

I have viewed few pages like, but they focus on application part, I want to know how to create sub domain and which hosting providers allow to do this. 
Please guide.
[URL Re-Writing in ASP.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310561/url-re-writing-in-asp-net)
https://forums.asp.net/t/1827778.aspx?+how+to+create+sub+domain+using+asp+net+c+

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know how to create sub domain and which hosting providers
>   allow to do this

This is very broad and it will differ for each provider so there's no straight answer for you.

At the basic level it's simply an `A`/`AAAA` or `CNAME` record for the sub-domain (or a wildcard if supported)  in the DNS zone for the primary domain.

You'd usually then need an entry in IIS to handle the host header, although using something like the `Default Website` and checking the host yourself could work.